# How to ignore eslint rules in electron-react-boilerplate project?

Tags: eslint, prettier, electron-react-boilerplate

There seem to be two linting rules in the electron-react-boilerplate project that are in conflict with each other.

```
onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) =>
   setSvg(e.target.value)
}

// react/jsx-curly-newline-problem
```

Fixing that causes

```
onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) =>
    setSvg(e.target.value)}

// eslint (prettier/prettier) problem
```

I have tried modifying the `/configs/.eslintrc` file but it has no effect. At least not on the linter running in VSCode nor the linter running as a pre-commit hook.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "off",
    "global-require": "off",
    "import/no-dynamic-require": "off",
    "jsx-curly-newline-problem": "off" // added
  }
}
```

So, how can I turn off any of these off? To be able to work in VS Code without errors and to be able to commit without using the `--no-verify` flag.